# Enter in a node and it disappears Arkit

Tags: swift, xcode, arkit

I created a sphere node using Xcode. When I get into the sphere, I can't see the sphere anymore because it disappears:

[image]

I don't understand why and how to see the texture of the sphere when I am inside it. The same happens when I use the app.

Comment: Texture is actually just on the surface. When you get inside, sphere doesn't disappear, you just no longer can see node's outer texture and instead you see inner.

Comment: @RobertDresler Thanks, do you know how to see the texture inside the node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set [`SCNMaterial.isDoubleSided`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnmaterial/1462531-isdoublesided) to `true`.